# when debugging in xcode an app that has cursor hidden, how can I force it to reappear

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb

In debugging a game that is full screen (on one of my two monitors) when it crashes and the debugger (on the other monitor, not captured) displays the crash location, the cursor is still hidden. Is there any way to force the cursor to reappear? I can click around blindly and it works, but it's not terrible accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't be of help with this, but may I ask you to report this as a bug to Apple, at http://bugreport.apple.com/
That way, maybe we'll all benefit from it in a few weeks or months when a new XCode gets out.

BTW, how do you hide your cursor? I thought that each process has its own private cursor. So, once you move the mouse to some other app, it should set the cursor anew.

Maybe you could use a different means of hiding the cursor in your game? E.g, instead of turning it off, leave it visible but give it an empty image.

Answer (score 0):

How did you hide the cursor? If you used CGDisplayHideCursor, you should be able to call CGDisplayShowCursor(x), where x is the main display id?

For example, in gdb, type:

```
call (unsigned long) CGMainDisplayID()
```

the id will be returned.

Then type:

```
call (long) CGDisplayShowCursor(id)
```

If you used Cocoa functions, you should still be able to call the appropriate Cocoa functions in the gdb console to display the cursor.